# dynamic fields(which are not part of mapping) appear in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am setting up ELK stack to monitor logs, and am using dynamic mapping to control created fields.

```
"mappings": {
  "applicationlogs": {
    "dynamic":  false,
...
```

use case : I should be able to see the fields in Kibana which I have defined in mapping, and the rest of the fields should not be seen in Kibana fields section.

Answer (score 1):

Kibana mapping is created independently of the Elasticsearch mapping, and the history is taken from the accessible indices. Kibana will show any field existing in an old or new index.